# calculate volume of intersection of utilization distributions

Tags: r, move, adehabitathr

I am trying to calculate the volume of intersection for the utilization distribution of many animals. I have estimated their UDs using `move::brownian.bridge.dyn()` for each animal then used `getVolumeUD()` which gives me the UD as a `RasterLayer`.

```
mod1 <- brownian.bridge.dyn(indiv, raster = xy, location.error = 10) #using default margin and window size
mod1.ud <- getVolumeUD(mod1)
```

To calculate the overlap I am trying to use `adehabitatHR::kerneloverlapHR` which requires the UDs to be an `estUDm` type object. I can make the individual UD into an `estUD` object

```
mod1.px <- as(mod1.ud, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
mod1.estud <- new("estUD",mod1.px)
```

But cannot figure out how to combine those into one `estUDm`. I've tried

```
all.ud <- c(mod1.estud, mod2.estud, ...)
class(all.ud) <- "estUDm"
vi <- kerneloverlapHR(all.ud, meth="VI", percent=95, conditional=TRUE)
Error in kerneloverlaphr(all.ud) : x should not be a volume under UD
```

I have also tried to make the estUDm object by stacking the UD rasters.

Any ideas? I'm open to a different method to calculate the volume intersection as well, just haven't found another method.

Thank you!